# Vue frontend stopped working after migrating to https

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ssl, websocket, wss

My vue frontend stopped work after I enabled SSL certificates. Now when I restart docker container I see only [image: error]
I also know that the url requested is (right side of the pic) [image: url]
Despite the fact that it should be wss in URL instead of ws.
The main point is that I can't control this websocket connection (I hadn't define this particular websocket). I tried to disable live reloading in vue.config.js:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  devServer: {
    allowedHosts: "all",
    hot: false,
    liveReload: false,
  },
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.symlinks(false)
  }
})
```

And saw similar problem in react: [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8079/files#diff-5166b8ed2c51bdab6a247a95b14ff595R62)

Nothing of this helped. I know exactly that my websocket server is available on wss://xxx/ws. What shall I do with this problem?

Comment: why are you trying to use develop mode using https?

Comment: @JaromandaX can you tell me please what shall I use instead? And is it really crucial in my case?

Comment: huh? is the question about developing, or are you trying to deploy your project and run in so-called "production" mode?

Comment: @JaromandaX my code worked locally, so my question is related to deploy

Comment: Does your code use websockets at all (I mean the code you wrote) - that websocket looks like the vue develop websocket used for "live reload" - you wouldn't ever use that in production

Comment: @JaromandaX, yes, I use websocket connection. Is the code needed?

Comment: "my question is related to deploy" - the problem is specific to webpack devserver, and you shouldn't run a devserver in production, especially since you disable hot reload, i.e don't need the features of a devserver. That you use ws in other places is irrelevant, it's webpack only. It's unknown how you enabled https, considering that webpack config doesn't reflect that. If you have a legit case, it's potentially solved with https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverserver .

Comment: @EstusFlask I enabled https with nginx, which represents an api gateway

Comment: This is a common option, but in this case you'd have to proxy devserver's ws traffic too. Any way, this looks like XY problem, you'd need to build an app and not run a devserver if you don't have a use for it (liveReload: false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basically yes, @EstusFlask and @JaromandaX were correct and migrating from vue dev server to nginx helped me. Thank you very much!